# OpenGL on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, opengl

I have my own game written in Java and it uses the Slick2D game library which uses OpenGL. The game has some multiplayer features so i need to start the server-software for the game on a Windows-Server, but OpenGL does not work because the Windows-Server is a VPS from a hoster. Is it possible to run software using OpenGL? My server-software runs on my home computer. Every other OpenGL software does not run on my windows server too.

Error-Message:

```
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not Windows Server 2012, it's the VPS itself. You will need a dedicated server as the VPS can't use the host's GPU, which is required by OpenGL.

Comment: Hmm I will recode my server-software without OpenGL. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Please assign it the best answer.